# Increasing the value of x in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, integer

I'm trying to edit the value of *bigalgs*, but when I actually print the value of *it*, it just spits the initial value of *bigalgs*, which is **0**. Why is this happening? Am I increasing the value of *bigalgs* the wrong way? I think it was by simply using the + sign... Maybe the *for loop*? Help!

(for reference, alg here means **algorism**)

```
class scinoteConvert:
    def __init__(self, num):
    
        alglog = []
        alglist = []
        bigalgs = 0
        num = str(num)

        for alg in num:
            alglist.append(alg)

        for alg in alglist:
            if int(alg) < 1:
                alglog.append(True)
            else:
                alglog.append(False)
                print(bigalgs)
                bigalgs + 1

        print(alglist, alglog, bigalgs)

input = int(input('Insert num: '))

if input < 1:
    exit('Error! Cannot calculate negative values!')

scinoteConvert(input)
```

Comment: use ```bigalgs += 1```

Comment: It worked! Thanks, I'm new to both programming and stack overflow, didn't expect to get an answer this quick! :D

Comment: It won't be the last time you make that mistake ;-)

Comment: You ought to call your ,`input` variable something else. As it is, you're overwriting the `input` function.

Comment: Ooooh, thanks for the tip! I'll try not to do it again :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct , But you should be in the syntax to add 1

```
bigalgs += 1
```

the code will become :

```
class scinoteConvert:
def __init__(self, num):

    alglog = []
    alglist = []
    bigalgs = 0
    num = str(num)

    for alg in num:
        alglist.append(alg)

    for alg in alglist:
        if int(alg) < 1:
            alglog.append(True)
        else:
            alglog.append(False)
            print(bigalgs)
            bigalgs += 1

    print(alglist, alglog, bigalgs)



input = int(input('Insert num: '))

if input < 1:
    exit('Error! Cannot calculate negative values!')

scinoteConvert(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write  `bigalgs =  bigalgs + 1` instead of `bigalgs + 1`.
When you write `bigalgs + 1` you do not change the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `+= 1`, so `bigalgs + = 1`, so your solution is

```
bigalgs =  bigalgs +=1
```

`because +=1 is for incrementing a variable by one in a loop`, so modify the object in-place if it's mutable. You only wrote bigalgs + 1.

Here's how to increase the bigals value the right way. That way when you print the bigals value, you shouldn't spit out its initial value 0.

```
class scinoteConvert:
    def __init__(self, num):
    
        alglog = []
        alglist = []
        bigalgs = 0
        num = str(num)

        for alg in num:
            alglist.append(alg)

        for alg in alglist:
            if int(alg) < 1:
                alglog.append(True)
            else:
                alglog.append(False)
                print(bigalgs)
                bigalgs =  bigalgs +=1

        print(alglist, alglog, bigalgs)

input = int(input('Insert num: '))

if input < 1:
    exit('Error! Cannot calculate negative values!')

scinoteConvert(input)
```